# Accuracy: C++11's binomial_distribution<int> not coincide with the what R returns

Tags: r, c++11, random, distribution

I need to generate samples in C++ that follow the hypergeometric distribution. But, for my case I can approximate it with the binomial distribution without any problem.

Thus I'd like to use the std implementation in C++11. If I generate many samples at calculate the probability I get different values from the one R tells me. What is more, the difference does not get any smaller when increase the number of samples increases. The parameters are the same for R and C++.

Thus the question: Why do I not get the same results and what can I do/which should I trust?

See below, the R and C++ code. The C++ program calculates the difference to the R values. Even if I let the program run for quite a while this numbers don't get smaller but just wiggle around the E-5, E-6, E-7 magnitude.

R:

```
dbinom(0:2, 2, 0.48645948945615974379)
#0.26372385596962805154 0.49963330914842424280 0.23664283488194759464
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class Generator {
public:
    Generator();
    virtual ~Generator();
    int binom();
private:
    std::random_device randev;
    std::mt19937_64 gen;
    std::binomial_distribution<int> dist;
};
Generator::Generator() : randev(), gen(randev()), dist(2,0.48645948945615974379) { }
Generator::~Generator() {}
int Generator::binom() { return dist(gen); }

int main() {
    Generator rd;
    const double nrolls = 10000000; // number of experiments
    double p[3]={};
    for (int k=1; k<100; ++k) {
        for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
            int number = rd.binom();
            ++p[number];
        }

        cout << "Samples=" << setw(8) << nrolls*k <<
            "   dP(0)="<<setw(13)<<p[0]/(nrolls*k)-0.26372385596962805154<<
            "   dP(1)="<<setw(13)<<p[1]/(nrolls*k)-0.49963330914842424280<<
            "   dP(2)="<<setw(13)<<p[2]/(nrolls*k)-0.23664283488194759464<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"end";
    return 0;
}
```

A selective output:

```
Samples=   1e+07   dP(0)=  -2.0056e-05   dP(1)=  9.49909e-05   dP(2)= -7.49349e-05
Samples=   1e+08   dP(0)=   1.5064e-05   dP(1)=  3.43609e-05   dP(2)= -4.94249e-05
Samples= 9.9e+08   dP(0)= -2.06449e-05   dP(1)=  5.93429e-06   dP(2)=  1.47106e-05
```

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment.

I don't see anything wrong with your numbers. You are doing 10**9 repetitions. Hence by the central limit theorem you should see accuracy around 10**(-4.5). That is indeed what you are seeing. That the signs of dP(0) and dP(2) fluctuate is another good sign. If you run your program multiple times, do the signs on the last line always show the same pattern. If not, that is another good sign.

Btw R is giving you way too many digits in my opinion. With doubles you only have about 15 digits of accuracy.

Comment: You say R is giving "too much accuracy" on the basis of inadequate evidence. The questioner has non-standard display options set, since I only see 8 digits displayed and I think my setup is bog-standard at the moment.